# Reduce image vertical spacing with text elements

Tags: spacing, graphics

I'm doing a .cls file and I want to reduce the spacing between the image and the title, the document looks like the following image

[image: Delete the space between the placeholder and the title]

The code for this, looks like this.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics[height=3.6cm,width=3.1cm]{./images/miniplace}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
  \LARGE{\scshape Institute of Extreme Resources Of Fun}\\
\end{center}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to place `\includegraphics` in a `figure` environment. In your case probably

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=3.6cm,width=3.1cm]{./images/miniplace}

  \LARGE\scshape Institute of Extreme Resources Of Fun
\end{center}
```

would do. If the graphics must be flush left, then say

```
\begin{flushleft}
  \includegraphics[height=3.6cm,width=3.1cm]{./images/miniplace}

  \centering
  \LARGE\scshape Institute of Extreme Resources Of Fun
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: Your comment lead me to the answer, I removed the figures wrapping also I added \vspace command. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
 {\includegraphics[height=3.6cm,width=3.1cm]{./images/miniplace\par
 {\centering\LARGE\scshape Institute of Extreme Resources Of Fun\par}
```

Don't use a floating environment for a logo, it might float off, also size commands don't take an argument, they are declarations that affect all following text in the same group.